# RUNDECK: Kerberos SSH Plugin stopped working from 4.9.0

Tags: ssh, kerberos, rundeck

The SSH Kerberos Node Executor i..e https://resources.rundeck.com/plugins/kerberos-executor-plugin/ is not working from version 4.9.0 for some reason.

I am not able to dispatch anything on the host configured with kerberos SSH, it is working fine till version 4.8.0. But any version above is causing it to fail.

It fails with error in the log "do_kdestroy" configuration not set but it is configured and working with previous versions properly.

Do we know the reason why? Do we have any fix planned for this?
There is new change introduced in 4.9.0 called Plugin Suite Configuration. Does it has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Open a new issue [here](https://github.com/cernops/rundeck-exec-kerberos/issues). Kerberos Node Executor is a third-party plugin (not an official plugin) and probably needs an update (the last stable version was from 2018 and the last change: was six months ago).